# AngularJS ng-submit fails on a Rails-generated form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, angularjs

I'm working with a Rails server (with Devise for authentication) and an AngularJS client. I've added a form generated by Rails to my client-side page, adding the `ng-submit` Angular directive like so:

```rb
<%= form_for("user",
    :url => user_session_path,
    :html => { "ng-submit" => "doSignIn()" }) do |f| %>
```

This generates a form with both `action` and `ng-submit` attributes, like this:

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" method="post" ng-submit="doSignIn()">
```

In the definition of the controller in the enclosing `div`, I have a `doSignIn` function that doesn't do anything at the moment:

```js
$scope.doSignIn = function() {
    console.log($scope.email, $scope.password);
};
```

`$scope.email` and `$scope.password` are bound using `ng-model`. Or, at least, they're supposed to be - I can't tell, because clicking on submit always results in being directed to `/users/sign_in`. I was under the impression that using `ng-submit` would prevent the form from redirecting the user. I have also tried adding an `ng-click` to the submit button, using the same method, which also uses the `doSignIn()` method, and I've even tried passing it the event and calling `event.preventDefault()`. Nothing seems to stop me being redirected.

My goal is eventually to perform sign-in with AJAX, but for now, just proving that I can stop the automatic redirect would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was under the impression that using ng-submit would prevent the form
>   from redirecting the user.

This is only a correct assumption if the `<form>` does not have an `action` attribute associated with it. When you use the Rails `form_for` helper, it generates an `action` for you when you specify a `url` attribute.

To keep the form from submitting, you'll have to follow the advice of Abraham P above, and `return false;` where you do not want the form to submit.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cleanest and most logical way to solve this problem was to add $event to the ng-submit function. Then I just did $event.preventDefault() in my js file. My code looks like this:

_form.html.haml

```
%div{:'ng-controller' => 'FestivalCtrl'}
  = simple_form_for festival, :html => {:'ng-submit' => 'addFestival($event)', :action => nil} do |form|
    = form.input :name, :input_html => {:'ng-model' => 'newFestival.name'}, :label => 'Festival Name'
    = form.input :description, :input_html => {:'ng-model' => 'newFestival.description'}
    %button{:type => 'submit'}
      Submit Festival

  {{newFestival.name}}
  {{newFestival.description}}

  %ul
    %li{:'ng-repeat' => 'festival in festivals'}
      {{festival.name}}
      {{festival.description}}
```

festivals.js.coffee

```
app = angular.module('MFN', ['ngResource'])

app.factory 'Festival', ($resource) ->
  $resource('/festivals/:id', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}})


@FestivalCtrl = ($scope, Festival) ->  
  $scope.festivals = Festival.query()

  $scope.addFestival = ($event) ->
    $event.preventDefault()
    festival = Festival.save($scope.newFestival)
    $scope.festivals.push(festival)
    $scope.newFestival = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false from your handler in order to prevent the form action from executing like so:

```
 $scope.doSignIn = function() {
     if($scope.email && $scope.password){
         return(true);
     else{
         return(false);
     }
 };
```

The assumption made above is that you want to submit if both the email and pasword are present, and do not want to submit otherwise.